# What does "the ear" mean?

Tags: meaning

Joseph Roulin says to Armand about Vincent:

> Joseph Roulin: Life can even bring down the strong. After **the ear**,
> nobody would even give him a chance. Even kids were tormenting him.

What does "the ear" mean?

Comment: It is important to give the context of your question.  Knowing that this is about Vincent Van Gogh lets us answer the question.  Without context, "the ear" doesn't mean anything to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversation is about the artist [Vincent van Gogh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh), who famously mutilated his own ear with a razor.

**The ear** refers to this event. It is not restricted to the ear itself.